# Passing the value from an input ID through a function

Tags: javascript

Within my PHP I have a while loop that is gong through the entries in the DB.

I would like to have a input where I can change a columns value.

```
<td><input type="text" id="cardId-<?php echo $cardId; ?>" /></td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick="update(<!-- pass cardId-0.val() -->)">Submit</button></td>
```

My JS

```
function update(id) {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("cardId-<?php echo $cardId; ?>").value;
    console.log(inputVal);
}
```

How can I make this work. No matter which one I click on, it only passes the first value in the first box.

Answer (score 0):

Delegation is a good idea

Please change

"table tbody"

and "mb-2"

to better selectors matching your actual markup

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.querySelector("table tbody").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("mb-2")) { // if tgt has a class mb-2
      const inp = tgt.closest("tr").querySelector("input[id^=card]"); // starting with "card"
      console.log(inp.id,inp.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="cardId-1" /></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="cardId-2" /></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="cardId-3" /></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="cardId-4" /></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```